# Two variable of string compared in batch

Tags: batch-file, md5

> The following is my code.
>
> ```
> @ECHO off
> SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
>
> SET targetFile=%1
> SET targetMD5=%2
>
> ::read MD5
> CALL md5.exe -n %targetFile% > md5.txt
> FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (md5.txt) do (
> SET FileMD5=%%i
> )  
> ECHO "FileMD5=%FileMD5%"
> DEL md5.txt
>
> ::read MD5.txt
> SET /A row=0
> FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in (%targetMD5%) do (
> SET OrgMD5=%%f
> ) 
> ECHO "OrgMD5=%FileMD5%"
>
> ::compare
> IF "%FileMD5%" EQU "%OrgMD5%" (
> ECHO 1
> ) ELSE (
> ECHO The target file was modified.
> ECHO 0
> )
>
> ENDLOCAL
> ```
>
> However, the result is:
>
> ```
> "FileMD5=468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A"
> "OrgMD5=468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A"
> The target file was modified.
> 0
> ```
>
> I think the FileMD5 is the same as OrgMD5. But the EQU operator doesn't think so.
>
> If i remove the quotes, and the code become:
>
> ```
> ::compare
> IF %FileMD5% EQU %OrgMD5% (
> ECHO 1
> ) ELSE (
> ECHO The target file was modified.
> ECHO 0
> )
> ```
>
> The result is:
>
> ```
> "FileMD5=468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A"
> "OrgMD5=468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A"
> 1
> The target file was modified.
> 0
> ```
>
> If i changed the code to:
>
> ```
> ::compare
> IF "%FileMD5%" EQU "468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A" (
> ECHO 1
> ) ELSE (
> ECHO The target file was modified.
> ECHO 0
> )
> ```
>
> The result is what i want, but the MD5 code should not always be 468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A.
>
> ```
> "FileMD5=468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A"
> "OrgMD5=468C15F33FC55E6A388D505024ED723A"
> 1
> ```

==============================================

I'm so embarrassing for the wrong code. So I corrected it as below.

```
::read MD5.txt
SET /A row=0
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%f in (%targetMD5%) do (
SET OrgMD5=%%f
GOTO compare
)

:compare
ECHO "FileMD5=%FileMD5%"
ECHO "OrgMD5=%OrgMD5%"
IF "%FileMD5%" EQU %OrgMD5% (
GOTO pass
) ELSE (
GOTO fail
)

:pass
ECHO 1
GOTO :eof

:fail
ECHO The target file was modified.
ECHO 0
GOTO :eof

ENDLOCAL
```

However, these "compare" always go to "fail".

```
"FileMD5=468c15f33fc55e6a388d505024ed723a"
"OrgMD5=468c15f33fc55e6a388d505024ed723a"
The target file was modified.
0
```

Comment: `ECHO "OrgMD5=%FileMD5%"` should be `ECHO "OrgMD5=%orgMD5%"` to display the value of `orgmd5`

Comment: I suggest to use `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('md5.exe -n %targetFile%') do set "FileMD5=%%I"` instead of `CALL md5.exe -n %targetFile% > md5.txt` and `FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (md5.txt) do (` and the next two lines. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for help on this command output on several pages. The option string `"delims="` might not be necessary if `md5.exe` just outputs the MD5 sum and nothing else.

Comment: use [fc](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) to verify for identical files (just to be sure...)

Comment: Sorry, I'm so embarrassing for the wrong code. So I edited and corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

In the edit you made you are comparing `"%FileMD5%" EQU %OrgMD5%`.

Just for an easier example imagine in both `FileMD5` and `OrgMD5` the value is `foo`.

The comparison would then yield: `"foo" EQU foo` Once with quotes and once without.

So you got two choices here: Leave the quotes out on the one side (usually should rather not do that) or put them on the other side as well.

Additional advice: To escape potential batch metacharacters I always use this to compare: `"x%var%" EQU "x%otherVar%"` (with the quotes and the leading x) to make sure I do not have parenthesis somewhere where I might not want them during runtime.
**NOTE**: As [@Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) noted in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293873/two-variable-of-string-compared-in-batch/45299964?noredirect=1#comment77581272_45299964), the x is irrelevant. It was something I picked up once and never let go of until now.

Comment: Your advice about include an `x` to "escape potential batch metacharacters" have no sense. A "x" letter does _not_ escape anything and any character enclosed in quotes (like parentheses) is not processed at runtime...

Comment: I see. I was actually wondering about that during writing. I once picked it up with this explanation in the back of my head and always used it that way. Will add a note for that :) Thanks for the hint @Aacini